How to set length \abovedisplayskip in preamble
I need to remove vertical space before all align environments. I found that I can \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} to achieve this. But this command only works when is written inside document environment. I would like to move it to preamble. Sample code:
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\begin{align*}
    q_1(t) &= \sum^{t}_{i=1} P(i) \\
    q_2(t) &= \sum^{255}_{i=t+1} P(i) \\
    \mu_1(t) &= \sum^{t}_{i=1} i P(i) / q_1(t) \\
    \mu_2(t) &= \sum^{255}_{i=t+1} i P(i) / q_2(t) \\
    \sigma^2_1(t) &= \sum^{t}_{i=1} [i - \mu_1(t)]^2 P(i) / q_1(t) \\
    \sigma^2_2(t) &= \sum^{255}_{i=t+1} [i - \mu_2(t)]^2 P(i) / q_2(t)
\end{align*}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\end{document}


You can use \AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}}. I'm sure there are already question(s) about this.

BTW: In the document preamble, after \documentclass{…} it would be more usual to use \usepackage instead of \RequirePackage.

You don't want to set \abovedisplayskip to zero. You rather don't want to have a blank line before any math display.

the space above your display is not a vertical skip it is a a spurious line of a paragraph with no text that is caused by the blank line in the source

Here's the output with your code:

Here's the output without

the setting to \abovedisplayskip;
the blank line before \begin{align*}.

As a general rule, there should never be a blank line in the input code before any math display. This appears to be the source of your problem and you're trying to cure the symptoms rather than the disease.
Remove all blank lines before math displays in the source. A blank line can follow, depending on whether the text after the display starts a new paragraph or not.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{align*}
    q_1(t) &= \sum^{t}_{i=1} P(i) \\
    q_2(t) &= \sum^{255}_{i=t+1} P(i) \\
    \mu_1(t) &= \sum^{t}_{i=1} i P(i) / q_1(t) \\
    \mu_2(t) &= \sum^{255}_{i=t+1} i P(i) / q_2(t) \\
    \sigma^2_1(t) &= \sum^{t}_{i=1} [i - \mu_1(t)]^2 P(i) / q_1(t) \\
    \sigma^2_2(t) &= \sum^{255}_{i=t+1} [i - \mu_2(t)]^2 P(i) / q_2(t)
\end{align*}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\end{document}



I want to keep blank line for aesthetic.

@Intolighter Don't. You're waiving TeX's method for avoiding a page break before a display. If you want to keep the display visually detached in the source, instead of a blank line use a line starting with %. I've been writing TeX documents for about 40 years and I never felt that need.

@Intolighter There is a recently built bridge in Venice, designed by a worldwide famous architect who, for aesthetics, decided that the steps would be made with glass. Unfortunately, being Venice a very humid place (no wonder!), people keep slipping on those steps.
